# How to query SQLAlchemy with an association table, an in clause and a sub query?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a course table and a student table defined as

```
class Course(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    tutor = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tutor.id"))
    students = db.relationship("Student", secondary=association_table)


class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    courses = db.relationship("Course", secondary=association_table)
```

and for a many to many relationship between them, I have created an associated table

```
association_table = db.Table(
    "association",
    db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column("course_id", db.ForeignKey("course.id")),
    db.Column("student_id", db.ForeignKey("student.id")))
```

I would like to query and get results of all courses taken by a particular student.
The SQL query would be like

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE course.id IN (SELECT course_id FROM association WHERE student_id = 2)
```

How do I do this using sqlalchemy?

One of my many failed attempts to do this is

```
query_ = self.session.query(Course)
query2 = self.session.query(association_table.course_id).all().filter_by(student_id=view_kwargs.get('student_id'))
query_ = query_.filter(Course.id.in_(query2)).all()
```

At present, I'm getting this when I'm calling this using API from Postman.

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'course_id'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` clause with sub-select is not the most elegant (and at least in the past, also not the most optimal way to execute the query).

In order to use `JOIN` clause with absolutely the same result please try the query below which is very succinct:

```
q = session.query(Course).filter(Course.students.any(Student.id == 2))
```

and will produce following `SQL`:

```
SELECT course.id,
       course.name
FROM course
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM association,
          student
     WHERE course.id = association.course_id
       AND student.id = association.student_id
       AND student.id = ?)
```

However, to avoid joining on the `student` table alltogether, the below more explicit query will result in the same outcome:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(Course)
    .join(
        association_table, 
        (Course.id == association_table.c.course_id) & (association_table.c.student_id == 2),
    )
)
```

which will result in the `SQL` similar to below:

```
SELECT  course.id,
        course.name
FROM    course
   JOIN association
     ON course.id = association.course_id
    AND association.student_id = ?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I actually found another query to be working for me, which is ``` session.query(Course).join(association_table).filter_by(student_id=view_kwargs['student_id']) ```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have found a solution that works and which is quite simple actually.
It goes like:

```
session.query(Course).join(association_table).filter_by(student_id=view_kwargs["student_id"])
```